# Representing Numbers in Exponential form

Tags: c#

I have a requirement to convert the following types of decimal numbers to exponential format

Number `0.00001`formatted as  `0.01E-04`

I use the following method for this: 
`string.Format("{0:E2}", dValue);`

But this returns `0.01E-004`

So I need to restrict the number of digits to 2 after the `E`.
Is this possible? If so: how ?

Comment: Well, need to restrict the number of digits after decimal and after E to 2. So it should represent it as 0.01E-04.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to use a custom format string to specify how to format your decimal:

```
string.Format("{0:0.##E+00}", dValue);
```

You can find more about custom numeric format strings on the MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx). There's a specific section on [Exponent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierExponent) formats.

Answer (score 7):

I *think* you want something like:

```
string text = dValue.ToString("0.###E+00");
```

(Change the number of `#` characters to change the number of decimal digits *before* the E.)

You can do this with a compound format specifier as well by calling `string.Format`, but personally I'd use a simple one unless you need to put other text round it anyway, in which case you'd use use something like:

```
string text = string.Format("Before {0:0.0###E+00} After", dValue);
```

Comment: @PranayRana: Sorry, I have no idea what you mean.